# How to print array values inside the form in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to print this array in a form. but it should generate automatically without writing in html file. I tried but I'm not getting the result.

This is to print the values and generate the result (need to write the code in .js file).

```
    result+='<form action="http://www.example123.com" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">';
    for(component in components){
    result+= mylogic(component,components);
    }
   "<div> <button >Submit</button> </div></form>";


    $scope.target_popup=function (form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');

    }


}) 

<html>
<div ng-bind-html="mylogic(result) | unsafe"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$sce.trustAsHtml(html)` render html from js

create a filter like this

```
.filter('trust',function($sce){
  return function(html){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
  }
})
```

call it in the html

```
 <div ng-bind-html="result | trust">

   </div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.result ='<form action="http://www.example123.com" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)"><div> <button >Submit</button> </div></form>';

})
.filter('trust',function($sce){
  return function(html){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-bind-html="result | trust">
 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: :-i tried to call in the way that i need to get my dynamic json inputs inside the form but its not working

Comment: module and basic components are missing in the codepen, please create a valid demo

Comment: :- can you please check now whats i made the changes you said ..  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybOjqv

Comment: :- thanks but still the submit button is not showing in the form why its not displaying?

Comment: since it is not part of the ng repeat it does not show inside ng repeat. put it outside the repeat. check the demo again

Comment: :- so will it come inside the forms or not?? or else it will be added as a seperate module?

Comment: its same module. but the form is separated

Comment: -is there any way to add the inside the form

Comment: you can't use nested ng-bind-html inside  ng-bind-html. One thing we can do is modify the result scope to `$scope.result  = '<div> <button >Submit</button> </div>';` and add the form tag in the html. check the demo again

Comment: :- is there any way to put everything inside an (id=result) and call only that in html page ..i have the example in javascript but i couldn't do it in angular??? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybOjqv

Comment: change the component array then

Comment: :- what do you mean by that?? i cannot change the type of json array its the desired format i want .

Comment: add additional property to component array as form and repeat it

Comment: :- sorry  i did'nt get that..i have to make the array into form format or what?

Comment: add additional field to component array and put the `result` string to that field

Comment: :-thanks for your help.. i will try now .if i face some difficulty hope you'll help

Comment: sure just try it